# Getting a column's data type in DB2 via AQT

Tags: jquery, sql, db2

I am trying to get the data type of a column in a DB2 db via AQT. I have not been successful using the following methods (they all say that sys.columns/information_schema.columns/etc are undefined)
The column's name is Updated_Timestamp

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers'
```

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTableName')
```

```
SELECT   o.Name, c.Name
FROM     sys.columns c 
         JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE    o.type = 'U' 
ORDER BY o.Name, c.Name
```

```
exec sp_help 'table_name'
```

```
show columns from 'dbname.tablename'
```

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TABLE_NAME')
```

Anytime I try to use desc and describe I get an error that says desc following desc is not valid, but there is only 1 desc in the statement... I attempted to use the Analyze menu in AQT but it only lets me select "Number of Rows" and no other options.

Answer (score 0):

There is no information_schema in Db2, but there are other similar tables/views. If you are on LUW you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM syscat.tables
WHERE tabname = 'Customers'
```

You can find out more about the catalog at [CATALOG VIEWS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2oc?topic=views-road-map-catalog). For information about columns [SYSCAT.COLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2oc?topic=views-syscatcolumns)

For your other queries, I guess:

```
SELECT * 
FROM syscat.columns 
WHERE tabschema = '...'
  AND tabname = '...'
  AND colname = 'UPDATED_TIMESTAMP'
```

EXEC in Db2 is CALL, but I'm not sure what sp_help does and if there is a counterpart.

Comment: Thank you. for some reason, syscat does not work in AQT. After some digging, I found that sysibm.syscolumns works though.

Comment: What Db2 platform are you on, I assumed LUW, but if you are on something else the views are probably named something else